# Django custom tags interactions

Tags: django, django-templates

I defined one custom tag `{% get_user user_id %}` which catch user's id and return user object through variable user_obj: `{{ user_obj.email }}, {{ user_obj.name }}, {{ user_obj.photo.url }}` and so on.

And it works fine. Next I defined tag `{% get_user_items user %}` which get user object and returns user's photo url through variable user_photo: `{{ user_photo }}`.

I want to make interaction between this 2 custom tags. It means smth like that:

```
{% load user_tags %}
{% get_user 1 %}
{{ user_obj }} // returns unicode string as expected
{% get_user_items user_obj %}
{{ user_photo }}
```

As I understand tag 'get_user_items' must get a user object through variable user_obj, **but no - it gets from variable user_obj the usual string 'user_obj', not object!!!**

How to fix this? What am I doing wrong??? How can I transmit value from variable `{{ user_obj }}` to tag `{% get_user_items %}` directly?

Thanks for your answers in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to resolve the string as a variable using the context. See discussion on [passing template variables to tags in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag)

```
class FormatTimeNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, date_to_be_formatted, format_string):
        self.date_to_be_formatted = template.Variable(date_to_be_formatted)
        self.format_string = format_string

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            actual_date = self.date_to_be_formatted.resolve(context)
            return actual_date.strftime(self.format_string)
        except template.VariableDoesNotExist:
            return ''
```

This is the example from the docs. You must first mark the value as a variable using `template.Variable`. The argument for that is the argument that holds the variable name. In the example, that's `date_to_be_formatted`. This is saved as an instance variable on the node so it's available later in the `render` method.

Then, in the render method, you attempt to resolve the Variable from the context (`render` has access to the context, which is why it's done here). This is done by calling `resolve` on the instance variable you created in the `__init__` method and passing it the context as it's argument. The variable could potentially fail to resolve, which is why it needs to be in a `try...except` block.

Comment: and how to do it (in few words)?

Comment: In other words, TL;DR. I've updated my answer to point out the pertinent bits and explain roughly what's going on, but at a certain point, you just need to dive into the docs or give up and go home.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot for so simple example.